# next.js prerendering error with next-intl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-intl

## Error occurred prerendering page "/en/500".

I bought this error wirth `reportToErrorTracking(error);`

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/500". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/next-intl/dist/production/react-client/index.js:1:171
    at c (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/.next/server/pages/_app.js:1:900)
    at Wc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at Zc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:209)
   Generating static pages (50/66) [   =] 
Error
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/next-intl/dist/production/react-client/index.js:1:171
    at c (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/.next/server/pages/_app.js:1:900)
    at Wc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at Zc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:209)
    at Z (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)

Error occurred prerendering page "/es/500". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/next-intl/dist/production/react-client/index.js:1:171
    at c (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/.next/server/pages/_app.js:1:900)
    at Wc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at Zc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:209)
    at Z (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
Error
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/next-intl/dist/production/react-client/index.js:1:171
    at c (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/.next/server/pages/_app.js:1:900)
    at Wc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at Zc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:209)
    at Z (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)

Error occurred prerendering page "/en/500". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/next-intl/dist/production/react-client/index.js:1:171
    at c (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/.next/server/pages/_app.js:1:900)
    at Wc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at Zc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:209)
 ✓ Generating static pages (66/66) 
> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /_error: /500
        /_error: /en/500
        /_error: /es/500
        /layout
        /layout: /en/layout
        /layout: /es/layout
```

## u [Error]: MISSING_MESSAGE

I get this error whenever I try to build.

```
u [Error]: MISSING_MESSAGE
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/createFormatter-46d61ef5.js:1:1859
    at exports.createBaseTranslator (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/createFormatter-46d61ef5.js:1:1909)
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/react.js:1:1412
    at Object.Kc [as useMemo] (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:60:240)
    at exports.useMemo (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:208)
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/react.js:1:1397
    at exports.useTranslations (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/react.js:1:1590)
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/next-intl/dist/production/react-client/index.js:1:140
    at m (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/.next/server/chunks/388.js:1:3940)
    at Wc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44) {
  code: 'MISSING_MESSAGE',
  originalMessage: undefined
   Generating static pages (50/66) [ ===] 
u [Error]: MISSING_MESSAGE
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/createFormatter-46d61ef5.js:1:1859
    at exports.createBaseTranslator (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/createFormatter-46d61ef5.js:1:1909)
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/react.js:1:1412
    at Object.Kc [as useMemo] (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:60:240)
    at exports.useMemo (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:208)
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/react.js:1:1397
    at exports.useTranslations (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/react.js:1:1590)
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/next-intl/dist/production/react-client/index.js:1:140
    at c (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/.next/server/pages/_app.js:1:900)
    at Wc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44) {
  code: 'MISSING_MESSAGE',
  originalMessage: undefined
}
u [Error]: MISSING_MESSAGE
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/createFormatter-46d61ef5.js:1:1859
    at exports.createBaseTranslator (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/createFormatter-46d61ef5.js:1:1909)
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/react.js:1:1412
    at Object.Kc [as useMemo] (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:60:240)
    at exports.useMemo (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:208)
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/react.js:1:1397
    at exports.useTranslations (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/react.js:1:1590)
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/next-intl/dist/production/react-client/index.js:1:140
    at u (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/.next/server/pages/_app.js:1:224)
    at Wc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44) {
  code: 'MISSING_MESSAGE',
  originalMessage: undefined
}
u [Error]: MISSING_MESSAGE
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/createFormatter-46d61ef5.js:1:1859
    at exports.createBaseTranslator (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/createFormatter-46d61ef5.js:1:1909)
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/react.js:1:1412
    at Object.Kc [as useMemo] (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:60:240)
    at exports.useMemo (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:208)
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/react.js:1:1397
    at exports.useTranslations (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/react.js:1:1590)
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/next-intl/dist/production/react-client/index.js:1:140
    at c (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/.next/server/pages/_app.js:1:900)
    at Wc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44) {
  code: 'MISSING_MESSAGE',
  originalMessage: undefined
}
u [Error]: MISSING_MESSAGE
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/createFormatter-46d61ef5.js:1:1859
    at exports.createBaseTranslator (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/createFormatter-46d61ef5.js:1:1909)
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/react.js:1:1412
    at Object.Kc [as useMemo] (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:60:240)
    at exports.useMemo (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:208)
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/react.js:1:1397
    at exports.useTranslations (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/use-intl/dist/production/react.js:1:1590)
    at /home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/next-intl/dist/production/react-client/index.js:1:140
    at u (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/.next/server/pages/_app.js:1:224)
    at Wc (/home/serokdilo/DEV/lavenus/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44) {
  code: 'MISSING_MESSAGE',
  originalMessage: undefined
 ✓ Generating static pages (66/66) 
 ✓ Collecting build traces    
 ✓ Finalizing page optimization
```

and my source _app.js code

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import "../styles/index.css";

import JsonLdComponent from "../SEO/jsonldConfig";
import NextSeoComponent from "../SEO/NextSeoConfig";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Preloader from "../components/PreLoader";
import Router from 'next/router';
import NProgress from 'nprogress'; // Yükleme bar stil dosyasını dahil edin
import 'nprogress/nprogress.css'; // NProgress stilini dahil edin

import {useRouter} from 'next/router';
import {NextIntlClientProvider, IntlErrorCode} from 'next-intl';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [longLoading, setLongLoading] = useState(false);
  let timer;

  NProgress.configure({ showSpinner: false }); // İsteğe bağlı konfigürasyon

//  useEffect(() => {
//    const timero = setTimeout(() => {
//      setLongLoading(false);
//      setLoading(false);
//    }, 2000);
//
//    return () => clearTimeout(timero);
//  }, []);


function onError(error) {
  if (error.code === IntlErrorCode.MISSING_MESSAGE) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    reportToErrorTracking(error);
  }
}
 
function getMessageFallback({namespace, key, error}) {
  const path = [namespace, key].filter((part) => part != null).join('.');
 
  if (error.code === IntlErrorCode.MISSING_MESSAGE) {
    return path + ' is not yet translated';
  } else {
    return 'Dear developer, please fix this message: ' + path;
  }
}
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const handleStart = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
          setLongLoading(true);
        }, 300);
      };
  
      const handleStop = () => {
        setLoading(false);
        if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
        setLongLoading(false);
      };
  
      Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handleStart);
      Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleStop);
      Router.events.on('routeChangeError', handleStop);
  
      // Component unmount edildiğinde event listener'ları temizle
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        Router.events.off('routeChangeStart', handleStart);
        Router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleStop);
        Router.events.off('routeChangeError', handleStop);
      };
    }, []);


    useEffect(() => {
      if (loading) {
        NProgress.start();
      } else {
        NProgress.done();
      }
    }, [loading]);

  return (
      <NextIntlClientProvider onError={onError} getMessageFallback={getMessageFallback} locale={router.locale} timeZone="Europe/Madrid" messages={pageProps.messages}>
        <NextSeoComponent />
        <JsonLdComponent />
        <Preloader loading={longLoading} />
        <Component {...pageProps} loading={loading} />
      </NextIntlClientProvider>
  );
}
```

Although this error is not received at the developer stage, it is also received during the build phase.
I couldn't find this week's solution anywhere, please help.

I couldn't even find what was wrong

Comment: I strongly recommend following along with their [Official Docs](https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started), first, update the package to the latest version, then follow the steps very carefully. There might be some steps that you haven't done.

Comment: I tried, but nothing changed